# Write the equation in cartesian form

Tags: matrices, vectors

I can't remember what method to use, help would be appreciated. 
The question:

A line is given by $r = 2i +3J -k + \lambda$. Write the equation in cartesian form.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't remember i will give a hint.

$$(\vec r- \vec r_0)=(\vec{r}-(2\hat i+3 \hat j - \hat k))=\lambda(\vec v)$$

This represent a equation of line passing through a point $r_0=2\hat i+3 \hat j - \hat k$ and parallel to a vector $\vec v$.

Substitute $\vec r=x\hat i + y\hat j + z \hat k$ and find individual component. And eliminate $\lambda$